# Classes not auto compiling in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, compilation

I am using Eclipse, In `struts.xml`, if I use:

```
<action name="hello">
            <result>
               /hello.jsp
            </result>
</action>
```

This works when I access `localhost:8080/app/hello`

But if I add a self-defined action class like:

```
<action name="hello" class="com.hah">
            <result>
               /hello.jsp
            </result>
</action>
```

The `hah.java` does not compile automatically, it gives me the exception:

```
Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/D:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:17:46
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:360)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:403)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5277)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Action class [com.hah] not found - action - file:/D:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:17:46
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:405)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:355)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:460)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:111)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
    ... 16 more
```

But I can make it work properly by compiling the `hah.java` manually(by using javac hah.java) and move the compiled `hah.class` into /D:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Struts2/WEB-INF/classes/ folder

I have checked `Build Automatically` and there is an entry "/src WEB-INF/classes " in `Deployment Assembly`.

So the problem is that the action class does not compile automatically. What can I do to make it compiled when Tomcat starts?

ps: Finally, I reinstall eclipse for Java EE and use struts-2.3.29, it works.
But I still do not know why..

Comment: delete war file, clean and build again

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: Without knowing your build environment, directory layout, etc. all we can do is guess.

Comment: Thank you Dava for your suggestion, What information else should I provide?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `Project > Build Automatically` is selected.

Also

Right click open project property and select `Deployment Assembly` check if the project target classes are copied into `web-inf/classes`

If these does not solve, I suggest you create an empty project and select `Dynamic Web Project` template, and copy your files in this new project.

Comment: This is not enough, if there's not an option to "Deploy Automatically".

Comment: By setting `Project > Build Automatically` the eclipse will always build the sources and put them in `target` folder. Before Eclipse starts the Tomcat, it will copy `target` including other resources which are defined in `Deployment Assembly` before.  How ever there is an `Automatically publish when resources change` in server options, which copy resources to `Tomcat`. I think the last one is what you mentioned !

Comment: I have checked "Build Automatically" and there is an entry "/src WEB-INF/classes " in Deployment Assembly of this project. I have also recreate the project from the very beginning(for the whole day...), but it still not works because there is not a class file in WEB-INF/classes.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to this:

Here's what was happening:
I had the exact same problem. Eclipse was not compiling the Java class into the .class file even if there were packages being created in the below path:

> [workspace_root].metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\2_StrutsReadingProject\WEB-INF\classes\

I tried manually compiling the class in the cmd prompt. Turns out I was missing the JAR files in the BUILD PATH. All my JARs were correct, there was no duplication. But it seems like Eclipse needs these JARs both, in your build path as well in your WEB-INF/lib folder.

After I added the JARs in both places and built the project again from Eclipse, the classes were compiled properly.

So here is how to add JARs in your Eclipse Build Path:

> Right click the project node in the "Project Explorer" > Build Path >
>   Configure Build Path > Switch to "Libraries" tab > Click "Add External
>   JARs" > Browse and select all your required JARs > Click "Apply" >
>   Click "OK".

Hopefully this will solve this error for many people!  If it doesn't, try manually compiling the class and the CMD prompt will show exactly any errors.

**MORAL OF THE STORY:** Eclipse does not show any errors in such a scenario, where the source of error is in its own operations!

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem and apparently this can be caused when deleting a library file (.jar) from disk (ie: in lib folder) but not removing it from the built path.

How I resolved it:

1. After deleting the .jar library from disk
2. Open Java Build Path. How:

   - In Project Explorer, right click on name of project and chose properties
   - In Properties window chose "Java Build Path"
3. Locate the respective entry (the file name you deleted)
4. And click on Remove
5. click on "Apply and close"

This will automatically rebuild the project if "Build Automatically" is selected (Menu: Project>"Build Automatically").